# known around here as 'Tall Bobby'

Tags: restrictive-clauses, dangling-modifier

a. I talked to the man who is the mayor of the town known around here as 'Tall Bobby'.

The man is known as 'Tall Bobby'. Does the sentence express that idea? Doesn't one thing that the town is known as 'Tall Bobby'? Do we have a dangling modifier here?

Comment: A comma after _town_ would remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's clear that the sentence means that the mayor is known as "Tall Bobby." If you want to make it more clear, add a comma after town to make it 'the mayor of the town, known around here as 'Tall Bobby."

Answer (score 2):

It is a dangling or misplaced modifer.  In writing you should probably consider rephrasing.

However its not a particularly bad or amusing example.  Pragmatically there is no doubt that "Tall Bobby" is a person's nickname, not a town's nickname. So "known as Tall Bobby" must describe the mayor, not the town.

Such misplaced modifers are not grammar errors, but examples of writing that can be improved for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the town. It's just a local nickname for the mayor. He's probably above average height (Tall)  and is called Robert (Bobby). It's similar to Elvis Presley being called "The King".